# Can't render video texture on iOS app using Kudan AR Unity plugin w/ Cardboard SDK

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, google-cardboard, kudan

I'm trying to replace my own SLAM code with Kudan Unity Plugin (1.2.1, native 1.2).
I've already succeeded in building and running sample app on my iPhone.
I also checked the plugin works on my Unity project on the editor.
But when I build it on my iPhone, it does not render the video background as like in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qH0Eq.jpg).

I attached:

- KudanTracker to a camera,

added:

- MarkerlessTransformDriver,
- MarkerlessTracking,
- and BackgroundRender
  as like in the sample.

I appreciate if someone give me some suggestions for what I'm missing.
Thank you in advance.

UPDATE (7/13):

I found that KudanSample scene also have same problem when Google Cardboard SDK plugin is added as shown in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVMcL.jpg).
In this case, I just imported Cardboard plugin and didn't add any prefabs in it to the scene hierarchy. It seems some plugin parts of Kudan and Cardboard are conflicting.

For trial, I deleted Cardboard's static library, libvrunity.a (and CardboardAppController.mm/h and entire "Cardboard" folder as they are referencing the library).
As the result, Kudan could render video background.

I also try to use the latest Google VR instead of Cardboard SDK, but the result was totally same as in the case of Cardboard.

I'd appreciate if someone knows how to fix it. Any suggestions are very welcome.

UPDATE (7/14):

As the signing problem of Xcode is now fixed, I'm checking the debug log.
It says "[KudanAR] Failed to create external textures".
It indicates _textureYp or _textureCbCr is null in TrackeriOS.cs.
_textureYpID and _textureCbCrId do not change whether I remove libvrunity.a or not.
Therefore, maybe there are something wrong with GetTextureForPlane().
I will keep you updated.

UPDATE (7/15):

I found that _textureYp and _textureCbCr are both null in TrackeriOS.
As they are results of GetTextureForPlane(), I hope it can be solved by changing parameters for the function. Since I could't find the documents for the function, I would be very happy if someone give me the information about it.

Comment: It says the tracker is running at 0Hz in your picture. Can you put breakpoints in the KudanTracker or possibly the TrackeriOS script to see why this might be the case?

Comment: Dear Neo, Thank you for suggestions!
But, unfortunately, I can't debug using breakpoints because of iOS signing problem (of course, it is not related to this topic), currently.
I'm looking into the codes you suggested now, and will try to put breakpoints after fixing singing problem.


I'm using Kudan AR together with Google Cardboard Plugin.
Do you think does it disturb rendering of Kudan?

I'm also checking the codes around Cardboard now.

Comment: Hi Neo, I added updates about Cardboard SDK above. Are there any way to solve this conflict? Thank you again for your support.

Comment: Version 1.2.2 of the Plugin did fix a problem on iOS involving YpCbCr being null. It was causing apps to crash when they loaded a new scene. It's a long shot, but it may also fix the problems you've been experiencing. Besides that, you could try removing the cardboard folder but leaving in libvrunity.a and see if that solves the compatibility problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for the fix and reply! I downloaded it again, and tested. But the result was same as reported before. A message "[KudanAR] Initialising v1.2.1 (native v1.2)" is displayed on the console. IMHO, what I can download from the [page](https://www.kudan.eu/download/) is v1.2.1, actually. Where can I get 1.2.2?

Comment: Sorry, it is 1.2.2 on the page, it's just displaying the wrong message in the console. What about the other solution, did it help at all?

Comment: Thank you for checking! But the other solution didn't work, I can't display video background without removing libvrunity.a, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem.
And I think this problem is very wired.

Please adjust Link Binary With Libraies of your xcode project setting build phases.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLYGh.png

Please follow this order. it's work for me.

```
libPhone-lib.a 
libgvrunity.a
libkudanPlugin.a
```